# Writing dbext query output in buffer to a CSV file

Tags: sqlite, csv, vim, dbext

I currently I have Vim set up with the `dbext` plugin to run queries against a database.  After running a query, it creates a new buffer for the output results.

So far, this setup works okay if I just want to see the output of a query, but instead I want to write the query output to a CSV file so that I can use it elsewhere.

Is there a good way to do this?

I found that if I go to the buffer and say `:w filename` I can save the output as a file, but the problem is that the default output from dbext isn't formatted like a proper CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

If your DB is PostgreSQL, then you can wrap your query in e.g.

```
COPY (<put-query-here>) TO STDOUT WITH (FORMAT CSV);
```

I believe there are similar solutions for other DBs.